# Tomcat ressource not available Java Web App AWS Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, vaadin

I am running a spring project with the Vaadin framework that connects to a PostgreSQL Database, and displays the data in a webapp. I used [this guide](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/building-a-web-ui-for-postgresql-databases) to get started, and basically just added some Vaadin components. When the mvn build is executed and subsequently the .jar file, I can connect to my web app through the browser at localhost:8080 and everything works just the way it is supposed to.

Now I want to deploy the app on an AWS Webserver. For this purpose, I created an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance (Configuration: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.2.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8). So far, so good. Thing is, when I access the webapp through the url handed by the INstance, I get an "HTTP 404 Status Code" and "Ressource not found". I was expecting the thing to at least start my web app, and then through an error because I didn't change the DB configuration. However, it seems to be making problems allready earlier. What am I doing wrong? I suppose it is something in the configuration of the Spring project, but am new to EE developement...

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>CompAS24</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CompAS24</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.spring.boot/mybatis-spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.1211</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!--        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
-->     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2g -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                <style>OBF</style>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/simple</runTarget>
                <module>AppWidgetset</module>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace ?

Comment: @RITZXAVI Do you mean the Instance logfiles?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS but I took a quick look over their _getting started guide_ and saw that they support both standalone applications and web apps deployed in containers (tomcat, glassfish, etc). Since you mentioned `Tomcat 8` in your setup I can only assume that it has been configured to run a web application so you probably need to deploy a `WAR` (web application archive) excluding the spring-boot embedded tomcat, instead of the standalone `JAR` you are now building.

Comment: @Morfic yeah allready did that, unfortunately the 404 status remains...

Comment: Ok, but what URL did you use? If your application was named `myapp` (myapp.war), I would expect something along the lines of `http://aws-address:aws-port/myapp` (eg: `http://myaws:8080/myapp`). And also, do you see anything weird in the logs?

Comment: Yeah that's the way I've been trying to access it.. I think the last line of the access log might be relevant (?): 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Oct/2016:11:18:27 +0000] "GET /MyApp0.0.1WAR HTTP/1.1" 404 1028

Comment: It this really the name of your packaged app `MyApp0.0.1WAR`, including `WAR` as well? Also, when I asked about the logs, I was suggesting to verify that the app has been indeed deployed and started to ensure that there's no issue with the app itself.

Comment: yes, that is the name. The file itself is called MyApp0.0.1WAR.war . And according to the elastic beanstalk log files, Tomcat is started properly, deploying and starting the web app succesfully.

Comment: Do you have a path specified for your app either in you `web.xml` (eg `<url-pattern>/myservlet/*</url-pattern>`), servlet configuration (eg: `@WebServlet(value = "/myservlet/*", asyncSupported = true,)`),  `@SpringUI` (eg: `@SpringUI(path = "/myservlet/*")`) or `application.properties` (eg: `server.servlet-path=/myservlet`) , whichever is applicable? At this point I think it may help if you could share the server startup logs, obviously leaving out any sensitive information...